# fitting two geolocation points in google map visible area

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, geolocation

Im trying to fit two geolocation points in google map visible area, But its not fitting. I used code below to achieve this

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: source, coordinate: destination)
self.mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 10))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AZa1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use includeCoordinate for that. It will fit all coordinates in bounds.

```
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(source)
bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(destination)
self.mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 10.0))
```

**Updated!**

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: source, coordinate: destination)
self.mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 100))

mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: self.bottomView.height, right: 0)
```

Comment: samet : Still Im facing the same issue. No luck.

Comment: Just increase padding, top marker will be visible. For bottom marker you should use mapView. padding because your bottomView override marker.

    `mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: self.bottomView.height, right: 0)`